# Huge drop in search traffic - I don't see any reasons for this

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, search

I've built a website that's been slowly increasing its users/day and now gets about 3k each day. The site uses a database to fill in some fields on the page and is optimized to do well in searches (which it does).

A week ago I noticed that I had a big drop in users and see that it's because the site isn't showing up in searches as much as before. I'm including a screen capture of WebMasters Tools to show what I'm seeing.

[image]

I've looked all over WebMaster Tools and Analytics to figure out why this is happening. I don't have any messages from Google. I do see a handful of errors (e.g. a few pages have problems on mobile) that I'll address, but I don't think that's the reason.

Can anyone suggest any reasons why I'm seeing such a big drop in traffic? What should I look at to try to figure this put?

Comment: I would suggest heading over to the [Google Updates and SERP Changes - June 2016](https://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4807611.htm) on Webmasterworld.   Look for other people that have reported problems around the same time.   If you can't figure it out from what others have said, post yourself.